# How can I show a Bootstrap 5 column only on mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a sortable table on the second column and dragging doesn't work well with it so would like to create some space before the column for dragging. How can I make the first column only show on mobile devices?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1 d-lg-none">
    Show only on mobile devices
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-11 d-block">
    Show on all devices
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're apparently already familiar with [Bootstrap's display utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements). What's the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for (`col-sm-1 d-block d-sm-none`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1 d-block d-sm-none">
    Show only on mobile devices
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-11 d-block">
    Show on all devices
  </div>
</div>
```